# Update column headertext in c# window app

Tags: c#

In the search form by display button records are displayed from database. but i wnt to 
change the header text of data grid column like member_id as memberID.

how can i do it?

as i m trying `datagridview.column[1].headerText="memberID"` it shows error of indexes of collection so what code i will use to change the header text?

Comment: Please cut down on the `...` and `***`, they only add noise to your question.

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact code? What you posted doesn't look right correct (shouldn't that be `Columns`?)

Answer (score 0):

try `grid.Columns[0].HeaderText = "memberID"`. Your column indices may be running out of bound.